# Ubuntu will not load since I updated to 14.10

Tags: boot

I have used the older versions over a year. After the latest update only the background shows.
After searching similar problems on online forums I did the following:
Ctrl-Alt-F1, I run xfdesktop, it installed itself (15MB), xfdesktop gave the error message:
"Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:"
What should I do next? (I am a newbie)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a computer for which I had changed unity to gnome. I think the gnome was the cause - I ended up reinstalling everything from scratch. But be careful when you do fresh installation because Ubuntu (at least in my language) did not make the options between replacing the current Ubuntu installation and completely formatting the drive clear.